# Converting text file to dictionary then to JSON object using Python - But I need to split data from the text file

Tags: python

I am trying to convert txt file data to a Python dictionary before dumping it to JSON and then writing JSON data into avro. My text file contains unwanted data that I need to remove, I only need field names and field types:

```
mappings = ['name', 'type']

with open('xxx.txt', 'r') as fn:
    dict1 = {}
    names = []
    types = []
    for line in file.readlines():
        names_lines = line.split()[0]  # index 0 = names
        names.append(names_lines)
        types_lines = line.split()[1]  # index 1 = types
        types.append(types_lines)

    id = 1
    for d in fn:
        desc = list(d.strip().split(' ', 1))
        name = desc[0]
        i = 0

        dict2 = {}
        while i < len(mappings):
            dict2[mappings[i]] = desc[i]
            i = i + 1

        dict1[name] = dict2
        id = id + 1
print(dict1)
```

1- My Error is:
name 'file' is not defined. Did you mean: 'filter'?***

Comment: `fn.readlines()`

Comment: When trying to print the dictionary I get an empty one.

Comment: I need to read the text file, remove unwanted data (I only need the data names and types) and then dump the dictionary to a JSON Object

Comment: Because you are consuming all the lines in the first loop, `fn` is empty in `for d in fn:`. You can merge both loop to a single loop.

Comment: Can you show an example?

Comment: what does the input data look like, and what is the output that you want?

Comment: As you can see, I need to remove the COMMENTS from each line and only have name & type in JSON format. Therefore, I need to convert my txt file data to a dictionary and then to JSON

Comment: so the output is a list of dictionaries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what you described you wanted in the comments, try this:

```py
records = []
with open('xxx.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        name, type_, *_ = line.split()
        records.append({"name": name, "type": type_})

print(records)
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245230/discussion-on-answer-by-anentropic-converting-text-file-to-dictionary-then-to-js).

Answer (score 1):

replace `file` with `fn`:

```
for line in fn.readlines():
```